# Adding a new Customer Group Programatically

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-group

I would like to know if it is possible from a public function to create a customer group? I would like, in my saveNewGroup function to crate a new customer group. I saw another example online but it was in a setup class and i cannot get it work

This is my class :

```
<?php

namespace XX\XX\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class SaveNewCustomerGroup extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_resource;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_customerGroupsCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupsCollection
    ) {  
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_customerGroupsCollection = $customerGroupsCollection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    //Every time the controller is called this function is executed
    public function execute(){
        $groupName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customergroup_name');
        $taxId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customergroup_taxid');

        echo json_encode($this->saveNewGroup($groupName, $taxId));
    }

    private function saveNewGroup($groupName, $taxId){
        if($groupName == null || $groupName == ""){
            return 'Error: Please enter a group name.';
        }
        else{
            return $groupName . " has been created successfully.";
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out the below code.

```
<?php

namespace XX\XX\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory as GroupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface as GroupRepository;


class SaveNewCustomerGroup extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_resource;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_customerGroupsCollection;
    protected $_groupFactory;
    protected $_groupRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupsCollection,
        GroupFactory $groupFactory,
        GroupRepository $groupRepository
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_customerGroupsCollection = $customerGroupsCollection;
        $this->_groupFactory = $groupFactory;
        $this->_groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    //Every time the controller is called this function is executed
    public function execute() {
        try {
            $groupName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customergroup_name');
            $taxId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customergroup_taxid');

            if($groupName == null || $groupName == "" ) {
                return 'Error: Please enter a group name.';
            }
            if($taxId == null || $taxId == "" ) {
                return 'Error: Please enter a taxId.';
            }

            // Create the new customer group
            $group = $this->_groupFactory->create();
            $group->setCode($groupName)
                ->setTaxClassId( $taxId);

            /** vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/GroupRepositoryInterface */
            $this->_groupRepository->save($group);
            echo json_encode( "Customer Group ". $groupName . " has been created successfully." );
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            return json_encode($e->getMessage());
            exit();
        }
    }

    /*private function saveNewGroup($groupName) {
            return $groupName . " has been created successfully.";
    }*/

}
?>
```